# How to create Android (AVD) Emulator on API level 15 (Android 4.0.3)

Tags: android, emulation, android-virtual-device

The AVD Virtual Device Configuration screen generally shows ARM and x86 system images, and allows for a developer to download images that are not yet downloaded.

However, although I do not have IceCreamSandwich/ API 15/ Android 4.0.3 downloaded, it does not give me the "Download" button option.

Question: how can I download the Android 4.0.3 image to create an AVD emulator for that OS version?

Screenshot attached:[image: Missing Download link]

Comment: FYI: I have already tried downloading the SDK Platforms "Android 4.0" and "Android 4.0.3" using the SDK Manager and updating the Android emulator to version 28.0.25.

Comment: I can download 4.0.3 now, it seems that your temporary network problem. Will you try again?

Comment: I am using Android Studio 3.3.2, and there is still no blue "Download" link next to the "IceCreamSandwich" release name. @StanleyKou what version of Android Studio are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "Download" option is not visible because it does not fit in the "Release Name" column. Expand the "Release Name" column and the "Download" option will appear.

Comment: Thank you! This was the exact issue, i'm amazed they didn't implement text wrapping.